# Problema con geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween() Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Encontré este código en Internet y lo intenté adaptar a mi proyecto, para obtener la posición actual.

En el jsp tengo las referencias:

```
<script src="repartidores/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MI_KEY&libraries=geometry"></script>
<script src="repartidores/js/posicionActual.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Y en posicionActual.js:

```
var registrandoPosicion = false;
var idRegistroPosicion;
var ultimaPosicion;
var lat;
var lng;

function registrarPosicion() {
    if (registrandoPosicion) {
        registrandoPosicion = false;
        navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(idRegistroPosicion);
        limpiarUbicacion();
    } else {
        idRegistroPosicion = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(exitoRegistroPosicion, falloRegistroPosicion, {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            maximumAge: 30000,
            timeout: 27000
        });
    }
}

function exitoRegistroPosicion(position) {
    if (!registrandoPosicion) {
        // Es la primera vez 
        registrandoPosicion = true;
        lat = position.coords.latitude;
        lng = position.coords.longitude;
        ultimaPosicion = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'localhost:8084/appRepartidores/PosicionActualServlet',
            data:{"latitud": lat, "longitud": lng}
        });

    } else {
        var posicionActual = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        if (google.maps.geometry.shperical.computeDistanceBetween(posicionActual, ultimaPosicion) > 100){
            ultimaPosicion = posicionActual;
            lat = position.coords.latitude;
            lng = position.coords.longitude;

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'localhost:8084/appRepartidores/PosicionActualServlet',
                data:{"latitud": lat, "longitud": lng}
            });
        }
    }

}

function falloRegistroPosicion() {
    alert('No se pudo determinar la ubicación');
    limpiarUbicacion();
}

function limpiarUbicacion() {
    ultimaPosicionUsuario = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
}

$('#localizar').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    registrarPosicion();
});
```

Al ejecutarlo y presionar el botón me tira este error:

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'computeDistanceBetween' of undefined or null reference posicionActual.js (37,13)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás usando

```
google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween
```

Y te dice

```
Unable to get property 'computeDistanceBetween' of undefined
```

Lo cual significa que

```
google.maps.geometry.shperical
```

Es undefined.

La razón por la que esto debe estar pasando es, probablemente, que no estás incluyendo la [biblioteca de geometría](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry?hl=es-419) de google maps.

Si ahora incluyes la biblioteca usando la URL

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Debes incluirla en cambio como

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=geometry
```

Edit: como bien me indica @juanmanuel, estaba mal escrito "spherical" y yo lo tomé de su pregunta tal cual, sin fijarme. Corregido y agradecido.

Comment: Gracias, pero el error esta en: .shperical.computeDistanceBetween, spherical está mal escrito.